# Finding a new Probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega = \{-2,-1,1,2\}$ and $\mathbb P :\mathscr P(\Omega)\to[0,1]$such that:
$$
\mathbb P (F)=\frac{\# F}{\# \Omega}=\frac{\# F}{4}
$$
and let $X$ be a random variable such that $X(\omega)=1+\omega^2$

Now, let $\mathbb Q :=\mathbb P^X : \mathscr B (\mathbb R)\to[0,1]$ be the distribution of X under $\mathbb P$.

I am really confused about $\mathbb Q$, how is this measure defined? How does one begin investigating it?

Comment: $ Q (A)=P (X \in A) $.

Comment: @Ian so $A \subset \mathscr B(\mathbb R) $ in this casE?

Comment: $ A \in B (R) $ actually. Another way to see it is that $ Q ((-\infty, y))=F_X (y)$. Now extend that to $ B (R) $.

Comment: @Ian I'm still confused, let's say we take $A=5$, then $\mathbb Q(A) = P(X \in 5) = P(\{-2,2\})$ ?

Comment: You should be writing $\{ 5\} $ but are otherwise correct.

Comment: Then, I just need to investigate the following cases: 
$$
A=\{5\} \implies Q(A) = 0.5 \\
A=\{2\} \implies Q(A) = 0.5 \\
A=\{7\} \implies Q(A) = 1\\
$$
?

Comment: $ X $ can't be $7$. You have $ Q (\{2,5\})=1$ and $ Q (\{7\})=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a discrete random variable with $$P\{X = 2\} = P\{X= 5\} = 1/2.$$

Because this $\Omega$ is finite, it seems to me we are making the usual choice that the sigma-algebra events, on which probabilities can be defined, consists of all subsets of $\Omega$ (the power class), and that the measure is 'counting measure' of points. (Notation is not exactly standard, so some words might have helped.)

Comment: "it seems to me we are making the usual choice that the sigma-algebra events, on which probabilities can be defined, consists of all subsets of Ω (the power class), and that the measure is 'counting measure' of points." ?? This is explicitely written down in the question. "(Notation is not exactly standard, so some words might have helped.)" ?? Notation is exactly standard.